# RDP To XP. Using internal IP works, external does not

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to remote desktop into a windows xp professional machine. I can use another computer on the network to RDP using the internal IP and it works fine... If I'm outside the network and use the external IP it does not work. I have port forwarded the RDP port.

This is the second time I have have this issue happen. The first time was with a server 2K3 machine, where I could get onto a server 2K8 machine on the same network just fine.(they were set to use different ports for RDP).
For that case, I now VPN in to the network and use the internal i.p this time.

For my case now, there is no VPN so that is not a solution. It seems to be something I am missing about the xp

Comment: Have you checked ipsec policies?  Was this machine always incapable of being RDPed into?

Comment: What does your network topology look like? maybe your ISP device has NAT as well?

Comment: Are there any group policies affecting the computer?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure remote desktop is turned on and that there is nothing blocking it on the firewall?

Answer (score 0):

VPN into your server, and then open a rdp remote connection to that XP computer via the local ip address. NO need to mess with the firewall/router.

Comment: this XP machine is in our office and not where our servers are located, we do not have a VPN setup here, unfortunately. 
VPN and then remote desktop is how i got into the windows 2003 machine, which was in the same location as the windows 2008 machine that worked OK.